# What is the difference between Shodasi and Shodasakasri?

Tags: sri-vidya, dasha-mahavidya

From a long time I thought that the shodasi in dasamahavidyas and shodasakshari given in the Srividya tradition are same but when going through the YouTube video of a guru he mentioned in between that there is a small difference between them. he mentioned in between a topic and didn't talk much  about the difference . So now my doubt is what is the main difference or that little difference between  the Shodasi and shodasakshari.is it the tattva difference or mantra difference or else there is no difference. please explain

Comment: Shodashi, when referred to the Mahavidya, is slightly different from Lalita Mahatripura Sundari. But when referred to a particular Mantra of the Sri Vidya, both Shodashi and Shodakshari refer to that same 16 letter Mantra.